# Asserting function calls inside a promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, mocha.js, sinon

I'm writing some tests for an async node.js function which returns a promise using the Mocha, Chai and Sinon libraries.
Let's say this is my function:

```
function foo(params) {
  return (
    mkdir(params)
    .then(dir => writeFile(dir))
  )
}
```

`mkdir` & `writeFile` are both async functions which return promises.
I need to test that `mkdir` is being called once with the `params` given to `foo`.

How can I do this?
I've seen quite a few examples on how to assert the overall return value of `foo` ([sinon-as-promised](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sinon-as-promised) is super helpful for that) but non about how to make sure individual functions are being called inside the promise.

Maybe I'm overlooking something and this is not the right way to go?

Comment: `mkdir` isn't called inside a promise, it's called synchronously from `foo` and you can test it like always? Or do you want to test that `writeFile` is called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mkdir` isn't called asynchronously here, so it's rather trivial to test:

```
mkdir = sinon.stub().resolves("test/dir")
foo(testparams)
assert(mkdir.calledOnce)
assert(mkdir.calledWith(testparams))
…
```

If you want to test that `writeFile` was called, that's only slightly more complicated - we have to wait for the promise returned by `foo` before asserting:

```
… // mdir like above
writeFile = sinon.stub().resolves("result")
return foo(testparams).then(r => {
    assert.strictEqual(r, "result")
    assert(writeFile.calledOnce)
    assert(writeFile.calledWith("test/dir"))
    …
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can mock the `mkdir` function then use `setTimeout` to check whether or not this function is called.

```
describe('foo', () => {
  it('should call mkdir', () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      let originalFunction = mkdir;
      let timer = setTimeout(() => {
        reject(`mkdir has not been called`);
      });
      mkdir = (...params) => new Promise(mkdirResolve => {
        //restore the original method as soon as it is invoked
        mkdir = originalMethod;
        clearTimeout(timer);
        mkdirResolve(someExpectedData);
        resolve();
      });
      foo(params);
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Even better: Don't use a timeout, but just hook on the promise that `foo` returns.

Comment: @Bergi I think that would be an interesting answer.