# Mock and assert a function call in a promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mocking

I'm writing some tests for a simple node.js module which returns the result of another function, currently that module looks like this:

```
const doAPostRequest = require('./doAPostRequest.js').doAPostRequest
const normalizeResponse = require('./normalizeResponse.js').normalizeResponse
const errorObject = require('./responseObjects.js').errorObject
const successObject = require('./responseObjects.js').successObject

exports.handlePost = (postData) => {
  return doAPostRequest(postData).then((res) => {
    const normalizedResponse = normalizeResponse(res);
    return successObject(normalizedResponse);
  }).catch((error) => {
    const { statusCode, message } = error;
    return errorObject(statusCode, message);
  });
}
```

`doAPostRequest` is another module that returns a promise. Now i want to test for the following cases:

1. if `doAPostRequest` is being called once with the params given to `handlePost`.
2. is `normalizeResponse` is being called once with the params that are returned from `doAPostRequest`.
3. is `successObject` is being called once with the params that are returned from `normalizedResponse`.
4. is `errorObject` is being called once with the params that are returned from `doAPostRequest` (if there is an error).

But i can't figure out how i can test if the functions are called within the promise and if `doAPostRequest` is being called in the first place.
Currently i have the following test suite for the module written with the help of the Chai, Sinon and Sinon-chai libraries.

```
const sinon = require('sinon');
const chai = require('chai');

const handlePost = require('./handlePost.js').handlePost
const params = { body: 'title': 'foo' }

chai.use(require('sinon-chai'));

it('Calls doAPostRequest', () => {
  doAPostRequest = sinon.stub().resolves("Item inserted")
  handlePost(params)
  expect(doAPostRequest).to.have.been.calledOnce;
  expect(doAPostRequest).to.have.been.calledWith(params);
});

it('Calls normalizeResponse', () => {
  normalizeResponse = sinon.stub().resolves("result")
  return handlePost(params).then((res) => {
    expect(normalizeResponse).to.have.been.calledOnce;
    expect(normalizeResponse).to.have.been.calledWith("Item inserted");
  });
});
```

However the tests fail with the following error response:
`AssertionError: expected stub to have been called exactly once, but it was called 0 times`

Maybe i'm overlooking something and is this not the right way to test this piece of code? I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38309221/asserting-function-calls-inside-a-promise) topic and the problem is close to identical, however for me non of the functions are getting called apparently. This leads to me thinking that i must overlook something. Any help and/or suggestions will be appreciated.